# Applying functions to some columns in a Dataset and keeping only those

Tags: dataset

Take the following example `Dataset`:

```
data = Table[Association["a" -> i, "b" -> i^2, "c" -> i^3], {i, 4}] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Picking out two of the three columns is done this way:

```
data[All, {"a", "b"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now instead of just returning the "a" and "b" columns I want to map the functions f and h to their elements, respectively, and still drop "c". Based on the previous result and the documentation of `Dataset` I hoped the following would do that:

```
data[All, {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the behavior is not like the one before. Although the functions are mapped as desired, the unmentioned column "c" still remains in the data.

Do I really need one of the following (clumsy looking) alternatives

```
data[All, {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}][All, {"a", "b"}]
data[Query[All, {"a", "b"}], {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}]
Query[All, {"a", "b"}]@data[All, {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}]
```

to get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: maybe `KeyDrop[data[All, {"a"->f,"b"->h}],"c"]`?

Comment: @kglr I'd say that fits in the "inelegant" category of which I gave three examples above. Don't you think so as well?

Comment: Sjoerd, i agree completely.

Comment: How about increasing kglr 's solution-elegance with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following expression might not qualify as *elegant*, but perhaps it can be scored as *less clumsy*?

```
data[All, <| "a" -> "a" /* f, "b" -> "b" /* h |>]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I like this solution. What I found inelegant in the other solutions is that you (seem to) drag around information (c in this case) that you don't need and that you throw away at the end. This feels inefficient. What if c contains a stack of MRI slices? You want to get rid of c as early in the process as possible and your approach seems to do that, at least to the eye. Whether this is actually more efficient would critically depend on the internal implementation of the process. Is it only pointers? Are actual copies of c made? Is an optimized execution plan generated that drops c at the start?

Comment: Implementation efficiency is a slippery thing in WL, especially if we take both speed and _memory_ into account.  Empirically, I have found that in WL the fastest execution plans often (somewhat counter-intuitively) involve lots of copying.  Associations (hash tries) are fairly well-behaved when it comes to copying so carrying around extra information is not _necessarily_ harmful.  My advice when it comes to performance is to benchmark using real data.  In this particular case, using V11.0.1, the exhibited query resolves to a doubly-nested `Map` that processes the data in one pass.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find @kglr solution inelegant, but perhaps a little prettier with

```
data[All, {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}] // KeyDrop["c"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but see the comment below WReach's answer about why I don't like my own solutions and this one.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody mentioned it, I will give a version with `KeyTake`

```
data[All /* KeyTake[{"a", "b"}], {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}]
```

[image]

Of course we can also do

```
data[All /* Map[Take[#, 2] &], {"a" -> f, "b" -> h}]
```